# Does Internet latency limit my clients to 120k synchronous transactions per hour?

Tags: udp, latency

Customer machines send UDP requests to our server.  The server processes each request and sends a response.  The logic of the transactions requires the client to wait for a response before sending a new request.

Even if all processing by client and server machines is instantaneous, it appears our customers still need about 30ms on average just to send/receive a round trip transaction over the Internet.  (That's traveling about 5,580 miles at light speed.)

Does that mean a given customer on average can't do more than about 120,000 synchronous transactions per hour?

1 transaction = .030 seconds minimum
120k transactions = 1 hour

Comment: Ask what distinguishes clients:  why cannot a customer pretend to be multiple clients and have multiple concurrent but each individually serial transaction streams.

Comment: @Steve-o: they can't pretend because they login via account numbers, and the system can tell if an account is sending a new transaction before the old transaction is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Impact of Latency**

Since you *must* serialize your requests, latency will limit your transaction rate.

However, the speed of light calculation is the theoretical best-case transit time.  In real life, there are routers along the way that add latency.

Be sure and measure the actual ping time at various points in the day, over several days, to get real latency numbers.

Since the client and server code will process in less-than-zero-time, and the processing time might well be at least as much as the latency time (depending on what you are doing), it may not be realistic to assume the processing time approaches zero.

**Overcoming Latency**

These days, there are a number of fairly inexpensive ways to put your servers (or at least a layer of your architecture) closer to your customers.  For example, you could consider using a service such as [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) to place processing resources in geographical proximity to your customers.  You can then either give e.g. West Coast customers a different URL to use than East Coast customers, or you can use geographic load balancing so that everyone can use the same URL (your load balancing service routes traffic to the best server, worldwide).  I have successfully used [UltraDNS](http://www.neustar.biz/enterprise/dns-services/what-is-external-dns) for that purpose in the past.

Comment: It's pretty clear the transaction restrictions are the limitation here: to quote "the client (has) to wait for a response before sending a new request."

Comment: @Steve-o: Perhaps I should finish my first cup of coffee before answering questions.  Read past that.  I'll update appropriately.